# I can't get more than one number in my EditText field when press the on screen buttons I created

Tags: android

I'm new to android development and I am making an app locker but when I am pressing the on screen buttons I created for the lock screen, the display in my EditText field only gives one number related to the button and wont add anymore to the line. It just overwrites the previously pressed button text. This is the code I have made so far:

```
public class ScreenLock extends AppCompatActivity {
Button b0;
Button b1;
Button b2;
Button b3;
Button b4;
Button b5;
Button b6;
Button b7;
Button b8;
Button b9;
Button bok;
Button bcancel;
EditText passdisp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_lock);
     b0= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
     b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     b2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
     b3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
     b4= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
     b5= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
     b6= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
     b7= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
     b8= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
     b9= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
     bok= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonok);
     bcancel= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoncancel);
     passdisp= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passDisplay);
}


public void buttonpress0(View view){
    passdisp.setText(b0.getText());
}
public void buttonpress1(View view){
    passdisp.setText(b1.getText());
}
public void buttonpress2(View view){
    passdisp.setText(b2.getText());
}
public void buttonpress3(View view) { passdisp.setText(b3.getText()); }
public void buttonpress4(View view){
    passdisp.setText(b4.getText());
}
public void buttonpress5(View view){
    passdisp.setText(b5.getText());
}
public void buttonpress6(View view){
    passdisp.setText(b6.getText());
}
public void buttonpress7(View view){
    passdisp.setText(b7.getText());
}
public void buttonpress8(View view){
    passdisp.setText(b8.getText());
}
public void buttonpress9(View view){
    passdisp.setText(b9.getText());
}
```

}
I know this is not efficient coding but it is my first draft and i would really appreciate any help resolving the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you keep setting the text, instead you must add to text using .append()

**so solution is**

replace `passdisp.setText(b5.getText());`

with `passdisp.append(b5.getText());`

for all buttons onClick methods

Comment: Thank you so much it worked great